# Wordpress - Link to .php file

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I made a link to a index.php page from a post but it doesn't seem to work. The "index.php" gets removed from the link and a page saying "That page can't be found." shows up instead. The page I'm linking to is in the right directory and the link is correct, but the page gets removed when the link is followed.

```
<a href="../cssexample/darkmetal/index.php" target="blank">
<img class="alignnone wp-image-63 size-medium" 
src="http://www.mjkrusing.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/design1-260x300.png" 
alt="CSS3 Page 1" width="260" height="300" /></a>
```

Why can't I link to the index.php?
You can have a look at the page on http://www.mjkrusing.com/programming/css3-dark-metallic-theme/

The picture is the link

Edit: The link works fine in post preview, but the problem occurs when I publish the post.

Comment: The page just doesn't exists?! You also don't have a index file in `cssexample/` and `cssexample/darkmeta/`

Comment: Yes, the index.php is located in that directory and linked correctly

Comment: NO, otherwise it would work!

Comment: @Rizier123 I have double-checked and checked again, the file IS there, the link IS correct, but the "index.php" gets removed from the browser address field when following the link and therefore it does not load the page.

Answer (score 0):

What if you change the link to

```
<a href="/cssexample/darkmetal/" target="blank">
```

Comment: The index.php seems to be removed when pressing the link so removing it from the link gave the same result.